# How to do if I want process separately in one image by using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have one image which is needed to be a processing separately.
for example,
I have got an image which has resolution 1024x768. and I got to separate by 4 block. then I will got that 512x368 the 4block of the image.
So I want to get the R average values from each block by using Matlab.

Does anyone know what the this ways to process?

Comment: you can use [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to split the image into blocks.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I think the first one has more feasibility.

Comment: stop acting like non-native English speaker. All the questions you have asked are luring other users to give you the solution for homework assignment on sympathy...This is a link where you are speaking ok English..http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/219279/how-to-borrow-time-in-sta